# how to make an operation wait until the other operation finish in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on an application which fetches data from api's
I'm using alamofire to fetch data
my question is how could I make an application wait until the data fetching finish

I'm using following code to fetch data

```
class abc:NSOperation{

static let sharedInstance = abc()

func main() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://playground.dzireinfotech.com/admin/event/getallevents", parameters: nil).response{
        (request, response, data, error) in

        if(error == nil){
            let jsn = JSON(data: data!)

            if let nn = jsn.array{
                let a = nn.count
                print("a\(a)")
                for(var i=0; i<a; i++){
                    self.e_Id.append(jsn[i]["e_id"].string!)
                    self.e_date.append(jsn[i]["e_date"].string!)
                    self.e_time.append(jsn[i]["e_time"].string!)
                    self.e_title.append(jsn[i]["e_title"].string!)
                    self.e_image.append(jsn[i]["e_image"].string!)
                    self.e_description.append(jsn[i]["e_description"].string!)
                    self.e_num_table.append(jsn[i]["e_num_table"].string!)

                    self.imgx.append(self.ImgURL + (jsn[i]["e_image"].string!))
                    // self.e_latitude.append(jsn[i]["e_latitude"].string!)
                    // self.e_longitude.append(jsn[i]["e_longitude"].string!)
                    //self.e_status.append(jsn[i]["e_status"].string!)
                }

            }

            if(self.imgx.count>0){
                FirstViewController.sharedInstance.loadData(self)
            }

        }else{
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine but it gives problem in following code

```
class pqr: UIViewController{

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    abc.sharedInstance.main()
    //I want to make wait here
    imageUrls = abc.sharedInstance.imgx
    let ab =  abc.sharedInstance.img_number
    print("ImageUrl\(imageUrls)")
    print("Image Number\(ab)")
    let urlx:NSURL = NSURL(string: imageUrls[ab])!
    self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(urlx)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all of this code into your viewdidload so that the app won't open until that code is finished running.

Are you trying to make it so the app stays on the launch screen until the the data has been fetched.

If I am correct you should just put the code in the viewdidload function it should say.

View did appear and then in the put the code correct me if I am wrong I am new to this.

Can you share the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Move all the code in `viewDidLoad` that depends on the long running operation to another method and then call that method in the completion handler of the long-running process.

Comment: @ ShahiM please give me any example to use completion handler